# how to drop an index key from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, indexing

I'm using sql server 2005/2008 and I have a table that it's PK (rec_index) is also indexed.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [rec_index] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    file_desc nvarchar(50),
    is_modified bit
)
```

However unfortunately I already have a table like this in my DB which O created without the index.

How can I ask if the table already is indexed do nothing, else add an index?  I can't drop it and than re-create it since i will loose data.

I'm looking for something like `"if not exists <index for rec_index> do <create index for rec_index>"`

Comment: 1) Yes, it's PRIMARY KEY is indexed. It's automatically indexed when it's declared as a PK, 2) You won't lose actual data by dropping an index, although an index rebuild can be time consuming, so you may still want to avoid it. Do you really want/need this separate index?

Comment: *'However unfortunately I already have a table like this in my DB which I created without the index.'* – do you mean that you didn't specify `CLUSTERED` after `PRIMARY KEY` in the script for that table? Or maybe you didn't specify `PRIMARY KEY` at all?

Comment: What do you want to do if you find a PK and it is not clustered? Or a clustered index already exists but it's not on the rec_index column? A table can only have one PK and only one clustered index - they don't have to be the same constraint/index. Also I agree with @Andriy - is the problem that the PK isn't clustered, or that there is no PK at all?

Comment: Also your question doesn't match the title. The title is "how to drop an index key" but the question seems to ask "how do I add an index only if it doesn't already exist?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( select * 
                  from sys.objects 
                 where parent_object_id = object_id('MyTable') 
                   and type = 'PK' )

do <create index for rec_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possibilities here, and I'm not sure which situation you're hitting, and what you want to do in each case:

```
USE [tempdb];

-- table with a clustered PK
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA(rec_index INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED);

-- table with non-clustered PK
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB(rec_index INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED);

-- table with no PK, no indexes
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableC(rec_index INT IDENTITY(1,1));

-- table with no PK, non-clustered non-unique index
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableD(rec_index INT IDENTITY(1,1));
CREATE INDEX d ON dbo.TableD(rec_index);

-- table with no PK, clustered non-unique index
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableE(rec_index INT IDENTITY(1,1));
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX e ON dbo.TableE(rec_index);

-- table with no PK, non-clustered unique index
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableF(rec_index INT IDENTITY(1,1));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX f ON dbo.TableF(rec_index);

-- table with no PK, clustered unique index
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableG(rec_index INT IDENTITY(1,1));
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX g ON dbo.TableG(rec_index);

-- table with unique clustered index, but PK on different column
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableH(rec_index INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     b INT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX h ON dbo.TableH(rec_index);

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TableA,dbo.TableB,dbo.TableC,dbo.TableD,
           dbo.TableE,dbo.TableF,dbo.TableG,dbo.TableH;
GO
```

You can certainly perform checks for each of these scenarios from the system metadata, and react accordingly. But you need to help us narrow down what you mean by "without the index."